# One Activity two different Layouts with own theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

Is it possible in Android to have a Activity with two Layouts and each of the layouts has his own theme?

Activity

- Layout landscape with android:theme="@style/MyTheme1"
- Layout Portraie with android:theme="@style/MyTheme2"

Comment: It's possible to detect orientation change and to change theme dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Folders `/res/layout-land` for landscape layouts and `/res/layout-port` for portrait.

The same you can do with styles if you want, just put them into `/res/values-land` `/res/values-port`